# Nginx redirect rule with arabic characters

Tags: nginx, redirect, system-administration

I need to create an Nginx rule that redirects `/ae/ar/أسافر%20من%20أجل/` to `/ae/en`. I've tried with these two rules:

- `rewrite (?i)^/ae/ar/أسافر%20من%20أجل(.*)$ http://$host/ae/en? permanent;`
- `rewrite (?i)^/ae/ar/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B1%20%D9%85%D9%86%20%D8%A3%D8%AC%D9%84(.*)$ https://$host/ae/en? permanent;`

But no one worked. Looks like the rule is ignored, any clues to make this rule work properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite does not see the percent encoded characters. You should be able to leave the arabic characters as they are (UTF-8 characters within the configuration file) and replace the `%20` with a single space. The entire regular expression should be surrounded with `"`s.

Alternatively, use a `location` statement:

```
location = "/ae/ar/أسافر من أجل/" { return 301 /ae/en; }
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked like a charm, you saved me a lot of time looking for a way to set this rule!
The rule was defined as: `rewrite "(?i)^/ae/ar/أسافر من أجل/(.*)$" https://$host/ae/en? permanent;`